# Sum of divisors of $n$ less than $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

It is easy to know the sum of divisors of $n$ just by calculating the prime factorization of $n$. Is it possible to calculate the sum of divisors of $n$ that is less than $k$ ($k<n$) without explicitly generating the divisors? For example, sum of divisors of $10$ less than $4$ is $1+2=3$. I thought it was not a hard problem but I cannot find any references or formulas related.

Comment: Algorithmically it would be at least as hard as factoring; you can let $k = \sqrt{n}$ and use this to factor cryptographic grade semi primes)

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I am aware of it. Actually I am expecting the algorithm to be much slower, just not involve constant powers of $k$ or $n$ in its complexity, since they can be very large.

Comment: The only shortcut is that you only need the partial factorization of $n$ , in other words it is sufficient to know all prime factors below $k$ (The powers can then easily be determined). Depending on the size of $k$, apart from trial division, some algorithms are known which cannot guarantee however to find all factors. If $k$ has no more than $20$ digits , ECM is a good possibility to find all factors upto $k$ with high probability.